# discord.py | Kick command errors with "list index out of range"

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
    @commands.command(name = "kick")
    @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def kick(self, ctx:commands.Context, member, *reason):

        member = re.findall(r'\d+', member)
        guild = ctx.guild
        memberToKick = get(guild.members, id=int(member[0])) # I think the error is here?

        if int(member[0]) == int(ctx.author.id):
          return await ctx.message.reply(content="You can't kick yourself.")

        if memberToKick:
            try:
                reason = " ".join(reason)
                
                await memberToKick.send(content=f"You were kicked out of {ctx.guild.name}! Reason: {reason}.")

                if reason:
                  await memberToKick.kick(reason=reason)

                  return await ctx.message.reply(content='User was kicked.')
                else:
                  await memberToKick.kick()

                  return await ctx.message.reply(content='User was kicked.')
            except:
              pass
```

We have user bob#4142, and I try quickly kick him using only "nickname":
**!kick bob**
And when I do that, it throws an error:
**IndexError: list index out of range**
How do I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`discord.utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils.get#discord.utils.get) to find a member by nickname:

```py
@commands.command(name="kick")
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(self, ctx: commands.Context, nick: str, *, reason: str):
    member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, display_name=nick)
    if member is None:
        return await ctx.send("Member not found.")
    # do your checks and kick the member
```